# Render useEffect/Async function from a difference screen

Tags: react-native

I have an `async function` and a `useEffect` that fetches data once.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

async function fetchData() {
    fetch(`${baseURL}api/v1/data/${userId}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        try {
          if (response.length > 0) {
            setData(response);
          } else {
            setData([]);
            // console.log(response);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('no response');
          alert(err);
        }
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [userId, data]);
```

I could remove the array on the use effect but it will always run the function if I do that.
So when I open the screen, it will fetch the latest data. However, if I want to add a new data from a different screen, it wont trigger the async nor the useEffect function. How should I tell RN that there is a new data? Would AsyncStorage work? to update a data from one screen and apply the data here? I am open for suggestions on how to proceed.

What I meant by a different screen: A register screen and a view screen. In this case, I already opened the View Screen before I open the register screen so view screen is already rendered.

Comment: Which navigation library do you use?

Comment: Sorry. I am also new to RN so I can only provide an explanation. What I meant was for example, a register screen and a view screen.

Comment: @Erinç, react-navigation/native

Answer (score 0):

In React Navigation and most of the navigation libraries, screens don't get unmounted from the stack when it's navigated to another screen. For example if you have a list of something and then you press to "+" button to navigate to the "new item" screen to add a new one, when you press back button, since the previous "list" screen was not unmounted from the stack, useEffect won't be triggered, and you won't get the new data.

There are a couple of solutions for this case:

- You can hold your data in a global state, and when you update an item from another screen, after a successful API call, you can also update the global state. You can look for React Context, MobX or Redux for this.
- You can pass parent's state with a callback from one screen to another if they are not that apart from each other. So that in the "new data" screen, you can call that callback function to change the parent screen's state too.
- Third, and IMO the best way is using a hook called useFocusEffect by React Navigation itself: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect

I hope these will help.